# Creating new datafreme with contidions in cordinates python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a dataframe (car crashes in NY) and this dataframe got this two columns: `['LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE']`. So, in a jupyter notebook i created this heatmap of the crashes with this info:
[First Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wkYN.png)

And i want to create three new dataframes with the three red circles in the heatmap (theese three: [Thre circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaT72.png). So, i found the center of theese circles an is this:

```
[40.760697660115106, -73.9648705595026]
[40.75656269439069, -73.99424647774494]
[40.696088299716685, -73.9846228443624]
```

After getting this, to make sure that i got a range and not just a single entry, i used this code:

```py
# Crear las condiciones para cada dataframe usando between
cond2 = df['LATITUDE'].between(40.76, 40.77) & df['LONGITUDE'].between(-73.96, -73.97487055)
cond3 = df['LATITUDE'].between(40.75, 40.76) & df['LONGITUDE'].between(-73.99, -74)
cond1 = df['LATITUDE'].between(40.69, 40.70) & df['LONGITUDE'].between(-73.98, -73.99462284)

# Filtrar el dataframe original usando loc y las condiciones
df1 = df.loc[cond1]
df2 = df.loc[cond2]
df3 = df.loc[cond3]

# Mostrar los resultados
display(df1)
display(df2)
display(df3)
```

But now i got three empty dataframes, how can i solve that?

Comment: & is a bitwise AND operator. Try using AND instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pandas function between() although not well explained in the documentation requires that the left argument be the smaller value in the range and the right argument be the larger of the two values in the range. Therefore the only issue with your code is that you need to switch the order of the latitude coordinates.

```
data = [[40.760697660115106, -73.9648705595026],
[40.75656269439069, -73.99424647774494],
[40.696088299716685, -73.9846228443624]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['LATITUDE','LONGITUDE'])

# Crear las condiciones para cada dataframe usando between
cond2 = df['LATITUDE'].between(40.76, 40.77) & df['LONGITUDE'].between(-73.97487055, -73.96)
cond3 = df['LATITUDE'].between(40.75, 40.76) & df['LONGITUDE'].between(-74, -73.99)
cond1 = df['LATITUDE'].between(40.69, 40.70) & df['LONGITUDE'].between(-73.99462284, -73.98)

#     LATITUDE  LONGITUDE
# 2  40.696088 -73.984623
#     LATITUDE  LONGITUDE
# 0  40.760698 -73.964871
#     LATITUDE  LONGITUDE
# 1  40.756563 -73.994246
```